# SCSS @each rule generating font-face's not applying on output

Tags: css, sass, each

Im currently trying to give my navigation some font-styling but only one style (the heaviest) font-weight applies to my text.

I've tried applying !important but didn't work out..

My @each generator looks like this:

```
$local-font-path: "../assets/webfonts" !default;

@each $weights in "100" "200" "300" "400" "500" "600" "700" "800" "900" {
@font-face {
     font-family: 'Poppins';
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: $weights;
     src: local(''),
          url('#{$local-font-path}/poppins-v15-latin-#{$weights}.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Chrome 26+, Opera 23+, Firefox 39+ */
          url('#{$local-font-path}/poppins-v15-latin-#{$weights}.woff') format('woff'); /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
   }}
```

CSS Output looks fine to me:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: "100";
  src: local(""), url("../assets/webfonts/poppins-v15-latin-100.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../assets/webfonts/poppins-v15-latin-100.woff") format("woff");
  /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: "200";
  src: local(""), url("../assets/webfonts/poppins-v15-latin-200.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../assets/webfonts/poppins-v15-latin-200.woff") format("woff");
  /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: "300";
  src: local(""), url("../assets/webfonts/poppins-v15-latin-300.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../assets/webfonts/poppins-v15-latin-300.woff") format("woff");
  /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
}

and so on...
```

The only one that wants to apply is font-weight:900; and idk why.

In dev-mode it also shows that everything is fine.. All sources found. code is right. I can't help it.. but maybe u can!

Pls help me out.

Comment: Change your font family name inside the loop.

Comment: `font-family: 'Poppins#{$weights}';`

Comment: Other commenters, font-family does not need to change. That's the purpose of using a single font family name and setting the font-weight. OP, are the other font-weights working?

Comment: Hi @disinfor, i also did that to Source Sans Pro, another font, and it works there. I really can't tell what's causing the errors. Im going to try something out...

Comment: Alright everyone I found out what was causing my issues on this one. Not sure why it was  like that, it still generated the code correctly. Anyway: ```font-weight: $weights;```was wrong and after I changed that one to : ```font-weight: #{$weights};``` it worked out.. Thank you guys!